# Passing an array/slice as a url parameter

Tags: go

I have a simple web server that intercepts geospatial map tile requests, swaps out pixels, and passes the image along to a front end to serve them. It works great, but the request is getting quite large. I was wondering if I could pass an array or slice instead? I couldn't seem to find anything searching. For example:

```
http://localhost:8002/tiles?url=url&r=0&g=250&b=0&a=230&replaceR=0&replaceG=127&replaceB=0&replaceA=0
```

is my typical request. I want to add more colors to swap so it would be great if I could pass something like:

```
http://localhost:8002/tiles?url=url&rgba1=[0,250,0,230,0,127,0,0]&rgba2=[250,0,100,100,200,0,20,180]
```

Is this possible? I tried to loop it like:

```
form := make(map[string][]uint8)
for k, v := range r.URL.Query() {
    arr := []uint8{}
    for i := 0; i < len(v); i++ {
        val, err := strconv.ParseInt(v[i], 10, 32)
        arr = append(arr, uint8(val))
        if err != nil {
        }
    }
    form[k] = arr
}
```

But it just prints [0]

Comment: Your GET request parameters aren't arrays. See this example https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parameters in GET request aren't arrays.

```
rgba1=0&rgba1=250&rgba1=0&rgba1=230&rgba1=0&rgba1=127&rgba1=0&rgba1=0
```

Creates an array rgba1=[0,250,0,230,0,127,0,0]

See https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values

Comment: So there's no way to just do, rgba1=[0,250,0,230,0,127,0] instead of the giant url?

Comment: @MitchellIngram You can parse it yourself, basically convert a string to an array of uint8s

Comment: Unfortunately, Go lang do not support this like in jersey or others. We need to come up with custom parsing logic.